# How add title on pin?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

```
for(int i=0;i<[btv_view.aray_cord count];i++)
{
    //dm.title=[appDelegate.lB objectAtIndex:i ];

    [mapView addAnnotation:[btv_view.aray_cord objectAtIndex:i]]; 

}
```

I have use above code for adding multiple pin annotation on map. Now i want add tiltle on each pin annotation. How do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (MKPlacemark* annotations in mapView.annotations) {
    annotations.title = @"your title";
}
```